Построить распределение вероятностей для случайной величины python
В задаче ученик сдает 6 независящих друг от друга экзаменов; вероятность не сдать каждый - 15%
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import factorial

n_exams = 6
failure_rate = 0.15

distr = []

Необходимо с помощью цикла посчитать вероятности не сдать 0,1,2,3 ... 6 экзаменов и записать их в список
Моя попытка:
for k in range(0, n_exams + 1):
    distr.append(
        failure_rate ** k
    ) 

результат:
[1.0, 0.15, 0.0225, 0.0033749999999999995, 0.00050625, 7.593749999999998e-05, 1.1390624999999997e-05]

Все так(вроде) кроме первого элемента в списке (ученик сдаст все экзамены)

Вы вообще считаете не то. Чему равна вероятность сдать все шесть экзаменов?

Нужно посчитать вероятность не сдать от 0 до 6 экзаменов, и записать в список эти значения, в последствии построить гистограмму

Задача нуждается в более чёткой формулировке. "Не сдать 6 экзаменов" можно понимать двояко. Как "не сдать каждый из 6 экзаменов" (или "не сдать 6 экзаменов подряд") и "не сдать хотя бы один из 6 экзаменов". Из имеющейся формулировки я бы не поручился, какой вариант имеется в виду. Для задачек по терверу архиважно чётко сформулировать проблему. Впрочем, это не только для них так.

Есть 6 независящих друг от друга экзамена, не сдать каждый по отдельности шанс 15%, необходимо на выходе получить список значений вероятности не сдать 0 из 6 экзаменов(то есть сдать все), 1 из 6 экзаменов, 2 из 6, и далее по аналогии до 6 из 6 экзаменов. У меня проблема в том что при failure_rate ** k первым числом в списке получается единица, а должно быть: единица - вероятность не сдать все экзамены (объяснил как смог, пишите пожалуйста если еще нужно уточнить что то)

Откуда вы взяли про единицу - непонятно, никакой единицы в результате не будет. Какие дискретные распределения случайных величин вы изучали? Какое подходит для данного случая?

Я имею ввиду что вероятность сдать все экзамены  = 1 - вероятность не сдать ни одного, если я не прав, пожалуйста объясните, как это правильно считается

А, это у вас минус. Нет, все равно неверно. 0.85^6=0.377149515625

Какова вероятность сдать один экзамен из одного? Какова вероятность сдать два экзамена из двух? Как эти две вероятности соотносятся друг с другом? Если в считаете, что это вопросы элементарные и не относятся к задаче, возможно, вы правы. Я пытаюсь выяснить, где именно вы начинаете ошибаться.

@MBo, да действительно, в таком случае как я могу решить эту задачу, получив это значение вместо единицы

Повторюсь: дискретные распределения случайных величин

Биномиальное распределение смотрели?

Ну что-то продвижения не видно. Давайте разберёмся.
Пусть вероятность провала одного экзамена f (fault), а сдачи s=1-f (success)
Если независимо сдаётся n экзаменов, то событие "провалено ровно k из них" означает, что мы можем выбрать одно из сочетаний (k из n) проваленных экзаменов, и таких сочетаний, как нам говорит комбинаторика,
 C(n,k)=n!/(k!(n-k)!)

Вероятность каждого одиночного сочетания есть произведение вероятностей событий - k провалено, и (n-k) сдано, т.е.
p = f^k * s^(n-k) 

а суммарная вероятность всех вариантов
P(n,k,f,s) = C(n,k) * f^k * s^(n-k)

Вот и получили биномиальное распределение (и стоит почитать учебник мадам Вентцель, она же писательница И.Грекова)
Итого:
from math import comb

f = 0.15
s = 1 - f
n = 6
P = [comb(n,k) * f**k * s**(n-k) for k in range(n+1)]
print(P)

[0.37714951562499993, 0.39933478124999994, 0.17617710937499995,
 0.04145343749999999, 0.005486484375, 0.0003872812499999999, 
 1.1390624999999997e-05]


Вам нужно биномиальное распределение. "В лоб":
import math
p = 0.15
q = 1 - p

def prob(n):
    return math.factorial(6)/math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(6-n)*p**n*q**(6-n)


for i in range(0,7):
    print(i, prob(i))

Это - вероятности не сдать соответствующее количество экзаменов
